# how to handle fixed position property in css when overlaps

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-web-developer

[this picture shows the overlapping of two div, in one div I took a table with two button floating right and in another div I worked on an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTOse.png)

[here the overlapping don't occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmD9A.png)

I described my overlapping problem above. I want them to look same always.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="first.aspx.cs" Inherits="first" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style>

        .buttonProperty{
            background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            float:right;
            margin-right:20px;



        }
        .buttonProperty:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        }


        .auto-style2 {
            height: 323px;
            background-image:url('images/img.jpg');
            background-size: 100% 100%;
           /*filter: grayscale(80%);*/ 
            filter: opacity(30%);
        }
        .tableProperty{
            position:fixed;
        }

        .auto-style3 {
            height: 154px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 526px">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <div class="auto-style3">
            <table style="width: 100%;" class="tableProperty">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="buttonProperty" runat="server" Text="Button" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="buttonProperty" align="right" runat="server" Text="Button" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


    </form>
    <div class="auto-style2" >
    </div>
    <p>sfsd</p><br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sfsd</p>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this question, but only a few RIGHT answers by actually seeing your code. Can you provide your code?

Perhaps you should change the position to relative instead of fixed. Margins and padding will may also  be affecting this.

I'll have a definite answer if I see your code.

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` is the culprit here. It's sort of like absolute positioning, in that it takes the element out of the normal flow (which usually looks like the element being rendered over other elements).

You can read up on positioning on the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position (MDN is a great source of documentation for HTML, CSS, and JS basics.)

The key part of what `fixed` does:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is
>   created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned
>   relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled.

You can fix this layout by using a different positioning type for the `.tableProperty`. (Based on the code provided, you probably don't need any positioning at all; that's equivalent to the default value of `position: static`.)